# Quotient of Graded Algebra is Graded

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, quotient-spaces, graded-rings, graded-algebras

Let $A$ be a graded algebra over a commutative ring, and $I$ a two sided ideal of $A$ which is not necessarily graded. We can take the quotient $A/I$ and obtain an algebra, however I am struggling to see why we need $I$ to be graded for $A/I$ to be graded.

For example, let $a\in A$ be arbitrary, then $a$ can be written as the finite sum:

$$a=\sum_na_n$$

where each $a_n$ is homogenous, i.e. $a_n\in A_n$. Since the projection is an algebra homomorphism, we have that:

$$[a]=\sum_n[a_n]$$

so each element $[a]\in A/I$ can be written as a finite sum over $n$, where each $[a_n]\in \pi(A_n)$, i.e. the restriction of $\pi$ to the subspace $A_n$. For brevity denote $\pi(A_n)$ by $(A/I)_n$, then it the above implies that:

$$(A/I)=\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty (A/I)_n$$

By the induced multiplicative structure on $A/I$ we have that for $[a_n]\in (A/I)_n$ and $[a_m]\in (A/I)_m$:
$$[a_n]\cdot[a_m]=[a_n\cdot a_m]\in \pi(A_{n+m})=(A/I)_{m+n}$$
so $(A/I)_n(A/I)_m\subset (A/I)_{m+n}$. Does this not imply that $(A/I)$ is graded? I suspect I have made some blunder somewhere, but I can't see it. I do see how we need $I$ to be graded to write:

$$A/I=\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty A_n/I_n$$

but I'm not sure why we need such a stringent condition for $A$ to admit some form of grading.

Edit:

Let $I$ be graded, and suppose that $[a]\in \pi(A_n)\cap \pi(A_m)$ for some $n\neq m$. It then follows that there exists an $a_n\in A_n$
and $a_m\in A_m$ such that:
$$[a_n]=[a]=[a_m]$$
implying that for some element $i\in I$:

$$a_n=a_m+i$$

Since $I$ is graded, we can decompose $i$ into a summation over homogenous elements $b_i\in A_i\cap I$, hence:

$$a_n=a_m+\sum_{i}b_i$$

This implies that:
$$\sum_{i}b_i=a_n-a_m$$
and since $i$ is a sum over homogenous elements, we have that $b_i=0$
for $i\neq n,m$, $b_n=a_n$, and $b_m=a_m$. This then implies that $a_n\in I\cap A_n$ and $a_m\in I\cap A_m$, hence:
$$[a_n]=[a_m]=0$$
so $\pi(A_n)\cap \pi(A_m)=\{0\}$ as desired.

Does this work?

Comment: I think you third display equation is the issue. For a direct sum $A/I = \bigoplus_n\pi(A_n)$ we need $\pi(A_i) \cap \pi(A_j) = \{0\}$ when $i \ne j$; why should this be true?

Comment: So, let's take an example of an ideal which is not homogeneous: $A = \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ with the degree grading, and $I = \langle y - x^2 \rangle$.  Then $y + I \in (A/I)_1$ and $x^2 + I \in (A/I)_2$; but $y+I = x^2+I$, and $y+I \ne 0+I$.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff Yup that's the problem, thank you.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff Is there an argument to be made for why this is true in the case where $I$ is graded? I have thought about it a little bit, and can't seem to come a conclusion

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff sorry for the spam, but please see my edit.

Comment: This looks good, I was about to write out a similar argument for you but you beat me too it :)